# Error initializing structures with helper function

Tags: c, struct, pass-by-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int j=0;

struct student
{
int CNE;
char Nom[20];
char Prenom[20];
char Ville[20];
float Note[3];
float Moyenne;
};

void read_struct(struct student stu)
{   
    stu.Moyenne=0;
    printf("Nom de l'etudiant:\t ");
    scanf(" %s",stu.Nom);
    printf("Prenom de l'etudiant:\t ");
    scanf(" %s",stu.Prenom);
    printf("CNE de l'etudiant:\t ");
    scanf("%d",&stu.CNE);

  }

 int main()
{   
struct student stu[10];
read_struct(stu[0]);
read_struct(stu[1]);
printf("%s \n %s \n",stu[0].Nom,stu[1].Nom);
printf("%d \n %d",stu[0].CNE,stu[1].CNE);

}
```

I m getting some weird output after compiling, the input from users are not saved in struct after calling them back.( sorry for my english)

Comment: `read_struct(struct student stu)` receives a copy of the struct so any changes made in that function are never seen back in `main()`. C is *pass-by-value*. You need to pass the address of the struct `read_struct(struct student *stu)` in order to update the struct at that address within the function. Your call in main would be, e.g. `read_struct(&stu[0]);`

Comment: Your `struct student` is passed by value to `read_struct()` so that function is modifying a local copy of the structure.

Search for "pass by value" and "pass by reference"

Comment: You pass the structure by value, i.e. your function `read_struct` uses a local copy of the structure which does not get passed to the calling `main` function. Change the function argument to a pointer to the structure and in `main` pass the address of the structure

Comment: That's worked thanks.
 but I had to change stu.Nom to stu->Nom, I got it from warning and it's worked, can you explain to me why should I change it too? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how this function is defined:

```
void read_struct(struct student stu) {
    ...
}
```

When you call this function, it passes in a *copy* of the `struct student`, so the function does its work to fill in the copy rather than the original.

You may want to have this function take in a pointer to the `struct student`:

```
void read_struct(struct student* stu) {
    /* You'll need to change things here */
}

read_student(&stu[0]);
read_student(&stu[1]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help.